# bpy.ops.sequencer.view_all() poll fails

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I ask for help because I literally have no idea what I have to do for this. I'm bangin my head for 2 days and I have to admit that I just dont get it...

I need a script to set the view in the sequencer to
bpy.ops.sequencer.view_all() (or similarly: bpy.ops.sequencer.view_selected())

To do that I need to override the context and tell the script it has to run that command in the sequencer area, if not it will give a:

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 4, in <module>
  File "F:\MEDIA\GAMES\Steam\steamapps\common\Blender\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.sequencer.view_all.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

..and of course just setting:

```
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'
```

..does nothing
But again I have absolutely no idea what to do so, any help would be highly apreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct context override:

```
import bpy

# go through all areas until sequence editor is found
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "SEQUENCE_EDITOR":
        override = bpy.context.copy()
        # change context to the sequencer
        override["area"] = area
        override["region"] = area.regions[-1]
        # run the command with the correct context
        with bpy.context.temp_override(**override):
            bpy.ops.sequencer.view_all()
        break
```

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect. I actually tried looping thru all areas, but there was something I just didnt understand. Thanks again!!!